# Bold Output Text in Qbasic

Tags: qbasic

I'm trying to get bold specific text, inside an input text field. I'm not sure how to go about it since q basic code isn't interpreted inside a text field, I've tried

```
10 REM PROGRAM TO PRINT A BOLD STRING 
15 CLS
18 PRINT "PLEASE INPUT YOUR MATRIC NUMBER"
20 INPUT M$
30 PRINT TAB(15); "YOUR MATRIC NUMBER IS "; M$; 
40 END
```

Comment: The console has no notion of formatting.

Comment: thanks. what about underlining a text??

Comment: The console has no notion of any kind of formatting, except color.

Answer (score 2):

You can print an underlined text only on a monocrome display by using the screen mode `0`.

Then you have to set the foreground color to `1` (underlined).

When you print on the screen, every character is underlined!

So, for example:

```
CLS
SCREEN 0
COLOR 1
PRINT "This String will be printed underlined."
END
```

Another solution will be on other screen modes drawing a line beneath the desired characters by using the `LINE` command:

```
CLS
SCREEN 8
PRINT "This String will HOPEFULLY be printed underlined."
LINE (0, 10)-(100, 10)
END
```

You have to work out the line position by yourself, so that your line will be displayed right under the characters.

Answer (score 0):

Placing underlines after text:

```
PRINT "This is a line of text."
PRINT "-----------------------"
```

otherwise, there is no way to underline text in basic on one line.